# change css in absolute div with parent div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="disp"> 
   <div>
      hi how are u
   </div>
   <div style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:100px;">
      hello
   </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#disp").css({"background-color":"#00ff00"});
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if u run this code it will print two div one is "hi how are u " and "hello" here one div has a green color one is white color i have changed color property with parent div.  my question is why next div is not getting green color i know the problem is absolute position how i can handle this situation

Comment: didnt get you,can you explain more

Comment: `i want to change the property of absolute position div with parent id` explain it in a better way.

Comment: so you want apply the parent div's css to the child div using parent's id?

Answer (score 1):

Just inherit the parent's **background-color** property:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:50px;top:100px; background-color: inherit">
```

Comment: @Francis Stalin whatever background-color you apply on parent div, the child div will inherit it.You can make your child div inherit other properties of parent div as well.Hope it helps you on your issue.

Comment: its working for background .if i want to handle the child div like change the content inside div something like that

Comment: @FrancisStalin Only css properties can be inherited.Unfortunately, the **content** is not one of them ;). But you can use javascript/jquery to dynamically add any div's content to other div, but for that you should provide it some id.AFAIK this is not the work of css.

Comment: sorry qwerty i have 4 reputation only its asking me min 15 for up

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can try this

```
$('#disp > div').eq(1).css('background-color', 'red');
```

hope this helps..

Comment: i want to give same color to all child div with parent id

Comment: yeah follow the same procedure just remove .eq() then it will select all children of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `nth-child` css selector (i.e. select the second child div in the `#disp` container):

```
$("#disp div:nth-child(2)").css({"background-color":"#00ff00"});
```

Then, you can modify your css styles as you wish.

Comment: is it possible with the single selection i have to give same color to all my child div.because i have random generated div i can't select child div here

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried but I'm wondering something like following would work:

```
$("#disp div).filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("position") == "absolute";
}).css({"background-color":"#00ff00"});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write css instead of jquery

```
   #disp > div {
     background:#00ff00;
   }
```

Comment: Why do you need to style in jquery?